# Non-default icon of OpenLayers Vector Feature

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, style

thats propably some minor problem, but i have deadline above my head and i can't get any clue whats wrong with my code, so I decided to come here for help. Im changing from markers to vector layer and i can't make my portal use any sort of non-default icon, whatever i put i externalGraphic style attribute doesnt have effect on map. I just see annoying orange circles.

Thats my code for layer and style:

```
var StylIkony = new OpenLayers.Style({
externalGraphic : '${symbol}',
graphicWidth    : 15,
graphicHeight   : 15,
cursor        : 'pointer'
});

var StylWarstwyIkon = new OpenLayers.StyleMap ({
default: StylIkony
});

warstwa_ikon = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Ikony Lokali");
warstwa_ikon.StyleMap = StylWarstwyIkon;
map.addLayer(warstwa_ikon);
```

And this is already executed code from creating point features:

```
WspolrzedneIkony = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(2279231, 7127620);
Ikona = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(WspolrzedneIkony,
    { "symbol": "grafiki/IkonyLokali/10.png", "idLokalu": 1 });
warstwa_ikon.addFeatures([Ikona]);

WspolrzedneIkony = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(2279245, 7127630);
Ikona = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(WspolrzedneIkony,
    { "symbol": "grafiki/IkonyLokali/6.png", "idLokalu": 2 });
warstwa_ikon.addFeatures([Ikona]);
```

Comment: Does "grafiki/IkonyLokali/10.png" refer to a valid path to a png file? You may need a full url reference to the file in there .. rather than a relative reference ..

Comment: I tried full reference, I even tried putting link to internet image internet instead of '${symbol}', and map still shows default markers. It's like my Openlayers.Style doesn't work or directs to default orange circle.

Comment: Do you have any clues what can be wrong? If nobody sees anything wrong in my code theres propably a problem in the other parts of my portal. I would be very grateful for an idea what to check. I tried to get any info from DOM and I can see the layer has defined StyleMap, and individual features have attributes given correctly, but the "style" box is set to null. By changing its value in debugger I only managed to got the point vector to disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inappropiate place of Openlayers.StyleMap assignment, it should be declared in the layer creation.